# java.lang.InstantiationError. Class becomes abstract

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am currently working on a Bukkit plugin for Minecraft and I am getting a java.lang.InstantiationError error while trying to create a new object. The stacktrace is as follows;

```
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationError: fancyui.craterhater.components.FancyComponent
    at fancyui.craterhater.uibuilder.ComponentMaker.getComponent(ComponentMaker.java:13) ~[?:?]
    at fancyui.craterhater.uibuilder.Editor_Page_0.getComponents(Editor_Page_0.java:40) ~[?:?]
    at fancyui.craterhater.uibuilder.Editor$1.call(Editor.java:36) ~[?:?]
    at fancyui.craterhater.masterfancyui.FancyUI.openInventory(FancyUI.java:195) ~[?:?]
    at fancyui.craterhater.uibuilder.Editor.createEditorGUI(Editor.java:236) ~[?:?]
    at fancyui.craterhater.commandhandler.MasterCommand$2.call(MasterCommand.java:69) ~[?:?]
    at fancyui.craterhater.commandhandler.CECommand.playerExecutes(CECommand.java:105) ~[?:?]
    at fancyui.craterhater.commandhandler.CECommand.checkPlayerExecutes(CECommand.java:98) ~[?:?]
    at fancyui.craterhater.commandhandler.MasterCommand.onCommand(MasterCommand.java:153) ~[?:?]
    at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:44) ~[1.8.jar:git-Spigot-870264a-0a645a2]
    ... 15 more
```

Line 13 of the ComponentMaker class simply says;

```
FancyComponent fancyComponent = new FancyComponent();
```

I did some debugging and decided to print the following;

```
System.out.println(FancyComponent.class.toGenericString());
```

This printed;

```
public abstract class fancyui.craterhater.components.FancyComponent
```

While the FancyComponent class is not abstract. Here is the FancyComponent class:

```
public class FancyComponent {

    //FancyComponent class represents the individual items placed in a FancyUI. 
    //It handles things such as animation, itemstack building and event handling whilst
    //allowing the FancyUI to handle loading and deleting of these components.
    //FancyComponents are added to the FancyUI by the user of the API using LoadFunctions.
    //They can also be generated from a FancyUI file.

    private FancyLocation fancyLocation;
    private FancyItemStack fancyItemStack;
    private FancyDisplayType fancyDisplayType;
    private String identifier = null;
    private int ID = 0;
    private int basicSlot = 0;
    private boolean copied;

    public FancyComponent() {
        fancyDisplayType = FancyDisplayType.DYNAMIC;
    }

    public FancyComponent copy(FancyLocation newLocation) {
        FancyComponent newComponent = new FancyComponent();
        newComponent.setDisplayType(fancyDisplayType);
        newComponent.setID(ID);
        newComponent.setFancyItemStack(fancyItemStack);
        newComponent.setFancyLocation(newLocation);
        newComponent.setAttributes(attributes);
        newComponent.setIdentifier(identifier);
        return newComponent;
    }


    //Method gets called when FancyUI decides to load in new FancyComponents.
    //This happens when openInventory gets called and new components are generated.
    //This method should start future animations. It should also handle ItemStack placement.
    //The boolean here represents whether or not it has succesfully been added. This is used in the
    //FancyUI in order to keep track of all active components and not the once off-screen.
    public boolean addToUI(Inventory inventory, Player p, FileConfiguration fc, FileConfiguration fc2) {
        if(fancyLocation == null) {return false;}

        return addToUI(inventory, p, fancyLocation, fc, fc2);
    }

    public boolean addToUI(Inventory inventory, Player p, FancyLocation fancyLocation, FileConfiguration fc, FileConfiguration fc2) {
        if(fancyItemStack == null) {return false;}

        FancyUI fancyUI = fancyLocation.getFancyUI();
        FancyLocation masterFancyLocation = fancyUI.getFancyData().getCurrentFancyLocation();

        if(!fancyLocation.isInView(masterFancyLocation, fancyDisplayType)) {return false;}

        int basicSlot = fancyLocation.getBasicLocation(masterFancyLocation.getX(), masterFancyLocation.getY(), fancyDisplayType);

        if(basicSlot < 0 || basicSlot >= inventory.getSize()) {return false;}

        this.basicSlot = basicSlot;

        ItemStack itemStack = fancyItemStack.buildItemStack(p,fc2);

        if(fc != null) {
            if(fc.contains("Components."+identifier+".Animations")) {
                for(String animation : fc.getConfigurationSection("Components."+identifier+".Animations").getKeys(false)) {
                    if(fc.getBoolean(("Components."+identifier+".Animations."+animation+".continious"))){
                        List<String> frames = new ArrayList<>();
                        if(fc.contains("Components."+identifier+".Animations."+animation+".animation")) {
                            frames = fc.getStringList("Components."+identifier+".Animations."+animation+".animation");
                        }

                        int interval = fc.getInt("Components."+identifier+".Animations."+animation+".interval");

                        if(interval < 1) {
                            interval = 2;
                        }

                        int position = fc.getInt("Components."+identifier+".Animations."+animation+".position");
                        boolean continious = fc.getBoolean("Components."+identifier+".Animations."+animation+".continious");
                        boolean reverse = fc.getBoolean("Components."+identifier+".Animations."+animation+".reverse");

                        fancyItemStack.startAnimation(frames, p, interval, position, this, continious, reverse);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if(fancyLocation.getFancyUI().getFancyData().isPlayerInventory()) {
            if(fancyItemStack.getCustomName().getFancyStringAnimations().length > 0) {
                fancyItemStack.startAnimation(fancyItemStack.getCustomName().getFancyStringAnimations()[0].getFrames(), p, 4, 0, this, true, false);
            }
        }

        inventory.setItem(basicSlot, itemStack);
        return true;
    }

    //Method to reload just this component. It is used when cycling through fancyLore. If a function makes changes
    //to other components the reload method in the FancyUI has to be called in order to fully reload a page.
    public void reload(Player p) {
        FileConfiguration fc = DataHandler.getFile(96,p.getUniqueId().toString(), false, "Data", "Users");
        ItemStack itemStack = fancyItemStack.buildItemStack(p,fc);

        if(fancyLocation == null) {
            return;
        }

        if(fancyLocation.getFancyUI().getFancyData().isPlayerInventory()) {
            p.getInventory().setItem(basicSlot, itemStack);
            return;
        }

        fancyLocation.getFancyUI().getFancyData().getInventory().setItem(basicSlot, itemStack);
    }


    //Method gets called when FancyUI deletes all information on other FancyComponents.
    //This happens when openInventory gets called and new components are generated.
    //Make sure that this method cleans up future animations so they don't go around throwing nullpointers.
    //The ItemStack itself is removed automatically by the FancyUI.
    public void notifyOfDeletion() {
        fancyItemStack.stopAnimating();
    }

    //Attributes are pieces of code written by the user of the API in order to have certain things
    //happen at certain events such as ON_CLICK or ON_DROP etc.
    private List<Attribute> attributes = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addAttribute(Attribute attribute) {
        attributes.add(attribute);
    }

    public List<Attribute> getAttributes(){
        return attributes;
    }

    public void setAttributes(List<Attribute> attributes) {
        this.attributes = attributes;
    }

    //Method to identify which Attributes need to run at these specific occasions. These occasions
    //may include things suchs as ON_CLICK or ON_1 just to name a few. This method consists of two
    //distinct parts. The first part handles all generated components which have scripts assigned to them
    //and the second part handles all components that have been generated by the plugin itself. And thus
    //do not have scripts assigned to them.
    public void handleEvent(FileConfiguration fc, FileConfiguration fc2, FunctionParams params, AttributeOccasion... attributeOccasions) {
        //The 'identifier' is a tag all generated components get. It is unique to all components. 
        //Non-generated components do not have this tag and thus we can check for null to see whether or not
        //it is generated.
        if(identifier != null) {
            if(fc.contains("Components."+identifier+".Scripts")) {
                for(String script : fc.getConfigurationSection("Components."+identifier+".Scripts").getKeys(false)) {
                    if(fc.contains("Components."+identifier+".Scripts."+script+".events")) {
                        List<String> scriptLines = fc.getStringList("Components."+identifier+".Scripts."+script+".script");
                        for(String event : fc.getStringList("Components."+identifier+".Scripts."+script+".events")) {
                            A: for(AttributeOccasion attributeOccasion : attributeOccasions) {
                                if(attributeOccasion.name().equalsIgnoreCase(event)) {
                                    fancyLocation.getFancyUI().getScriptParser().executeScript(params.getPlayer(), scriptLines, FancyUI.fancyUI.get(params.getPlayer().getUniqueId()), params.getFancyComponent(), fc2, false);
                                    break A;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if(fc.contains("Components."+identifier+".Animations")) {
                for(String script : fc.getConfigurationSection("Components."+identifier+".Animations").getKeys(false)) {
                    if(fc.contains("Components."+identifier+".Animations."+script+".events")) {
                        for(String event : fc.getStringList("Components."+identifier+".Animations."+script+".events")) {
                            A: for(AttributeOccasion attributeOccasion : attributeOccasions) {
                                if(attributeOccasion.name().equalsIgnoreCase(event)) {
                                    List<String> frames = new ArrayList<>();
                                    if(fc.contains("Components."+identifier+".Animations."+script+".animation")) {
                                        frames = fc.getStringList("Components."+identifier+".Animations."+script+".animation");
                                    }

                                    int interval = fc.getInt("Components."+identifier+".Animations."+script+".interval");

                                    if(interval < 1) {
                                        interval = 2;
                                    }

                                    int position = fc.getInt("Components."+identifier+".Animations."+script+".position");

                                    boolean continious = fc.getBoolean("Components."+identifier+".Animations."+script+".continious");
                                    boolean reverse = fc.getBoolean("Components."+identifier+".Animations."+script+".reverse");
                                    fancyItemStack.startAnimation(frames, params.getPlayer(), interval, position, this, continious, reverse);
                                    break A;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //Handles all components generated by the plugin as well as generated components from file if this component is inside of an editor.
        //If inside an editor generated components will have some attributes linked to them by the plugin. If not inside an editor, generated components
        //will not have any attributes linked to them. 
        A:for(Attribute attribute : attributes) {
            for(AttributeOccasion attributeOccasion : attribute.getAttributeOccasions()){
                for(AttributeOccasion attributeOccasion2 : attributeOccasions) {
                    if(attributeOccasion.equals(attributeOccasion2)) {
                        attribute.getAttributeFunction().call(params);
                        continue A;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //This method is used to move the cursor in list cycleables. 
    public void performCursorMove(int delta, Player p) {
        if(fancyItemStack == null) {return;}
        FancyLore fancyLore = fancyItemStack.getFancyLore();
        if(fancyLore == null) {return;}

        fancyLore.moveCursor(delta, p);
    }

    public void setCursorPosition(int n, Player p) {
        if(fancyItemStack == null) {return;}
        FancyLore fancyLore = fancyItemStack.getFancyLore();
        if(fancyLore == null) {return;}

        fancyLore.setCursorPosition(n, p);
    }

    public int getSlot() {
        return basicSlot;
    }

    public FancyLocation getFancyLocation() {
        return fancyLocation;
    }

    public FancyItemStack getFancyItemStack() {
        return fancyItemStack;
    }

    public void setFancyItemStack(FancyItemStack fancyItemStack) {
        this.fancyItemStack = fancyItemStack;
    }

    public void setFancyLocation(FancyLocation fancyLocation) {
        this.fancyLocation = fancyLocation;
    }

    public void setDisplayType(FancyDisplayType fancyDisplayType) {
        this.fancyDisplayType = fancyDisplayType;
    }

    public void setIdentifier(String identifier) {
        this.identifier = identifier;
    }

    public String getIdentifier() {
        return identifier;
    }

    public void setIsCopied(boolean copied) {
        this.copied = copied;
    }

    public boolean isCopied() {
        return copied;
    }

    public void setID(int ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public FancyDisplayType getFancyDisplayType() {
        return fancyDisplayType;
    }
}
```

The weird thing is that this does not occur on later versions of Spigot. I have tested this on 1.8, 1.9, and 1.15 and the error occurs on 1.8 and 1.9 but not on 1.15. Any help would be appreciated.

It appears to only not throw the error on the latest version (1.15). All other versions do throw the error.

After a few hours of testing I decided to copy paste the code of the problematic class into a new class. I renamed all references to this class. This fixed my issue but I am not particularly happy with it especially because the original name is still causing the error. So if I rename the new class to the old name the error reappears.

Comment: You are probably *running* a version of the class that is not the one you think you are running.

Comment: Do you know a way I can test or check what version of this class I am running?

Comment: Maybe start with your packaged archives, just compare the files. Or inspect your dependency tree from whatever build tool you use.